# How can i bind dynamic formula result in result input field based on dynamic calculator using Angular6?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a situation where i have to generate dynamic calculator with dynamic fields.  Like if i have to generate "Percentage Calculator" so that's calculator fields are specific and if i have to generate "Compound Interest" Calculator so that's calculators input fields are definitely different. Both calculators will have different formula also. So i have succeeded to generate dynamic calculators.

i have 2 components. One is `HomeComponent`and other is `CalculatorComponent`. I am calling `CalculatorComponent` in `HomeComponent`. I am passing `JSON` from `home.component.ts` like this

```
this.dynamicFormJson = {
  heading : 'Percentage Calculator',
  totalFields : 3,
  inputs : [
    {label : 'Percent', placeholder : 'Enter Percentage Here', type : 'number', variable : 'percent'},
    {label : 'Amount', placeholder : 'Enter Amount Here', type : 'number', variable : 'amount'},
    {label : 'Result', placeholder : '', type : 'number', variable : 'res'}
  ]
}
```

Here is my `calculator.component.ts` code in which in am creating dynamic variables for each input field and binding that dynamic variables to dynamically created input fields

```
import { Component, OnInit , Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-calculator',
 templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
 })
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

 @Input() formJson : any;
 formInputsVar = {};
 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.formJson.inputs.map((item : any)=>{
  if (!this.formInputsVar[item.variable]) {
    this.formInputsVar[item.variable] = '';
  }
 })
}
 onSubmit(){
  console.log(this.formInputsVar);
 }

}
```

By this approach i am succeeded in creating dynamic calculator and generate dynamic variables and then assign to input fields and getting values from that click event `onSubmit`.
Here is my complete working code on 
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wf9vx)

Now i am looking for that how can i implement formula in a way that when user enter values in input fields and then it will calculate result and show in result input field real time like Angular 2 way binding. I will add formula in json object of `inputs` array but i am stuck on the fact that how can i implement formula on input fields dynamically because each calculator will have different `JSON` and different formula.

Here is [reference website](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/percentage)

If i have formula in the same json of calculator like this

```
this.dynamicFormJson = {
  heading : 'Percentage Calculator',
  totalFields : 3,
  inputs : [
    {label : 'Percent', placeholder : 'Enter Percentage Here', type : 'number', variable : 'percent'},
    {label : 'Amount', placeholder : 'Enter Amount Here', type : 'number', variable : 'amount'},
    {label : 'Result', placeholder : '', type : 'number', variable : 'res'}
  ],
formula : "percent * amount / 100"
}
```

So how can i implement this formula on my dynamically created calculator.

**Note** 
Calculator's json will be different for each calculator and formula will be different for each calculator also.

You can see on reference website's calculator functionality. I want exactly same. You can check other calculators also. I am using Angular6

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, the following 2 changes to your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wf9vx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcalculator%2Fcalculator.component.ts) will get what you're looking for:

A few notes:

- calculator can have **n** number of fields
- I am assuming that the operator will be multiplication' (*to have any other operator, just change the mathematical operator inside the loop in the function `updateResult` - to make it completely dynamic, consider getting the operator as a user input also*)
- the last item in your `dynamicFormJson` will always be used to store the calculated result (*this is why we are looping from 0 - this.formJson.inputs.length-1*)

**Added** updateResult() in **calculator.component.ts**, complete code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() formJson : any;
  formInputsVar = {};
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formJson.inputs.map((item : any)=>{
      if (!this.formInputsVar[item.variable]) {
        this.formInputsVar[item.variable] = '';
      }
    })
  }

  updateResult(){
    var tempMultiplicationValue =1;
    for(var i=0; i<this.formJson.inputs.length-1; i++){
      tempMultiplicationValue = tempMultiplicationValue * this.formInputsVar[this.formJson.inputs[i].variable];
    }
    //this.formInputsVar['res'] = this.formInputsVar['percent'] * this.formInputsVar['amount'];
    this.formInputsVar['res'] = tempMultiplicationValue;
  }


  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.formInputsVar);
  }

}
```

**Added** `(change)="updateResult()"` in **calculator.component.html**, complete code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <form style="margin:100px 0 0 100px;background-color: lightgrey; padding: 20px;">
      <h2>{{formJson.heading}}</h2>
      <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let inputRow of formJson.inputs">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">{{inputRow.label}}</label>
        <input type="{{inputRow.type}}" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="formInputsVar[inputRow.variable]" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (change)="updateResult()" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="{{inputRow.placeholder}}">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working properly. I want that when user will enter value in last input field before result input field then result should be shown in result field real time like angular 2 way binding. Your stackblitz link is not working.

Comment: i didnt paste a new stackblitz... use your stackblitz and update the TS and HTML file with the code from my post...

Comment: But the issue here is that calculator will be generated dynamically so how can i assign the change event on dynamically created second last input field (Input field before result field)

Comment: Additionally there is no change method for input. There is ngModelChange event for input ngModel value changes.

Comment: wait - let me do a new stackblitz which will hopefully make it clear

Comment: ok but just keep in mind the fact that calculator will be created dynamically as i have number of differenct calculators so there is not just multuplicaiton r addition calculators. So i have to make it dynamic to create calculator dynamic and assign update function dynamically to the second last field (input field before result field).

Comment: check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2ofas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188648/discussion-between-fahad-hassan-subzwari-and-akber-iqbal).